# How to move files from one zfs filesystem to a different zfs filesystem in the same pool?

Tags: zfs

I have two filesystems in the same zfs pool, `/mnt/fs_a` and `/mnt/fs_b`.  I want to move about 1TB of data from `fs_a` to `fs_b`.  But when I:

```
mv /mnt/fs_a/mythtv_recordings /mnt/fs_b/
```

to my surprise it starts copying the files block-by-block.  Given the time it took to move a 2GB file, it looks like this operation would take days of massive thrashing to finish.

There has to be a much smarter and faster way to do this, right?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is "No".  There isn't a faster, or smarter way to do this.

ZFS filesystems (even though they are on the same pool) are separate filesystems.  Neither `mv` nor any other tool can just move the block pointers or whatever so that files that were on `fs_a` are now on `fs_b`.

(BTW, multiple formatted partitions or LVM volumes on the same disk or raid array are also separate filesystems and `mv` devolves to copy-and-delete for them too)

This issue has come up several times over the years (with some talk of creating a tool to do what you want) and as I understand it, the major difficulty that puts it in the too-hard basket is the question of how to handle snapshots - if there are snapshots of `fs_a`, the blocks would be in both fileystems at the same time.  The same is true of files that have hard-links.

I've run into it myself numerous times (e.g. when moving files between datasets as you did, or when I need to convert a subdirectory to a fs), and have just learnt to put up with the inconvenience.  It can be a major PITA.

if `fs_b` is empty or doesn't yet exist and you want to move the **entire** contents of `fs_a` to `fs_b` (and not just some or even most files & directories) you can use `zfs rename` to rename `fs_a` to `fs_b`.  I suspect that this is not relevant to your situation, though.

There's an open issue on this for ZFSOnLinux at https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/2991

I haven't searched but I would expect that upstream [OpenZFS](http://open-zfs.org/)  and even Sun/Oracle ZFS probably have similar bug-reports/feature-requests.

BTW, see also https://serverfault.com/questions/584693/freenas-why-isnt-mv-command-instant-within-a-raidz1-volume

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response.  I appreciate the rename suggestion, but as you suspect I have even more data on that I don't want on b.  At least I can move on now, and copy the files via a buffer disk to at least eliminate the thrashing.

Comment: Hello, I just realized, this is relevant, i was trying to accomplish near the same thing. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219786/bulk-remove-a-large-directory-on-a-zfs-without-traversing-it-recursively

Comment: Wouldn't dedup be able to alleviate this to some extent?

Comment: @sean ZFS's dedupe is a great way of substituting very expensive RAM for dirt-cheap disk.  There are a few use cases where it's a good idea (like a VM or container host with dozens or hundreds of near-identical VMs/containers) but in most cases, it's worse than useless.   Even in cases like the VM host, the main benefit is the reduced I/O demand & improved performance from reading the same blocks from cache, not from storage savings - disk storage is cheap and plentiful.  RAM is expensive and a far more limited resource. Even SSDs are cheap compared to RAM.